# Dynamically replace all urls to full absolute url in template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template which I am going to send as an email.
Thus I need to have absolute full urls (along with protocol and domain name) instead of relative ones.

The content in the email is going to come dynamically from database (entered using ckeditor, so I **CAN NOT** do something like {{ protocol }}{{ domain_name }}{% static '' %}. This would work only for static files. However the media content uploaded via ckeditor will recide in media files and I have absolutely no control over it.

Also i cant use javascript as it is an email template.

Currently I have built a python function which scans the entire template after rendering and prepends the protocol and domain name to every **src** attribute in **img** tag and all **href** attributes.

I would like to know if any better way exists

Answer (score 0):

You can use [request.build_absolute_uri](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) and make a custom template tag in order to used when rendering your mail template.

### Example

```
#templatetags/url_helper.py
@register.simple_tag()
def full_uri(request, relative_url):
    return request.build_absolute_uri(realtive_url)
```

Then ...

```
{# Some template.html #}
{% full_uri request some_img.url as full_img_url %}

<img src={{ full_img_url }} />
```

Comment: That's the issue. I can not do <img src={{ full_img_url }}/> because that part is automaticaally rendered fromthe ckeditor. 
All I have is a content variable. And I do {{ content|safe }} and it renders the html content along with image tags